# bluetooth class doesnt stick

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to set up bluetooth on my pi3.
I've tried following a few guides (starting from a fresh install each time), but each time I hit the exact same problem.

Following [this guide](https://thecodeninja.net/2016/06/bluetooth-audio-receiver-a2dp-sink-with-raspberry-pi), I've done the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth bluez-tools
sudo gpasswd -a xbian pulse
sudo gpasswd -a xbian lp
sudo gpasswd -a pulse lp
sudo gpasswd -a xbian audio
sudo gpasswd -a pulse audio
sudo sh -c "echo 'extra-arguments = --exit-idle-time=-1 --log-target=syslog' >> /etc/pulse/client.conf"
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hciconfig hci0 class 0x200420
sudo reboot
```

However, after a reboot, if I run `hciconfig hci0 class` it shows a class of `0x000000`

If I then use bluetoothctl to set discoverable on and pair to a device, I get told the device has switched to class 0x4

Any ideas what the heck I'm doing wrong?

(bluez is version 5.24, raspbian is jessie/pixel January release)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. In my case, I'm trying to turn my Pi into a Bluetooth speaker, so I defined `Class = 0x20041C` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`. It worked the first time, but since rebooting it now uses class `0x00041C` (same kind of device, but it drops the audio service class and my phone no longer connects). Tried overruling with `hciconfig`, but it doesn't work :/

Comment: Looking a bit closer, `hciconfig` sticks until I use `discoverable on` in `bluetoothctl`.

Comment: Or maybe not . Tried pairing without turning discovery on and connection still failed (and class reverted when I tried). No idea what's going on.

Comment: Any progress on this one?

Comment: nope. gave up in the end